# FullCalendar views - agendaDay and basicDay

Tags: fullcalendar

We are trying to use both the agendaDay and basicDay views in FullCalendar. However the button for each view is a duplicate - aka we cannot change the title of the button. How can we implement both views with a different button for each?

Using v1.6.3

Comment: as I can understand you are displaying same calendar in two different views ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the captions of the buttons in general with the [`buttonText`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/buttonText/) option:

```
buttonText: {
    prev:     '&lsaquo;', // <
    next:     '&rsaquo;', // >
    prevYear: '&laquo;',  // <<
    nextYear: '&raquo;',  // >>
    today:    'today',
    month:    'month',
    week:     'week',
    day:      'day'
}
```

It's looking for me that fc doesn't support using two of the day/week views in parallel as there are no different keys for the agenda variants. Neither in the doc nor in the [defaults](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/defaults.js) file on GH. You could file an issue on the [tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list).